# For each SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access

We have a database that contains information about time booked to projects. We have a live record for a project, that holds the correct time information (imported from SAP once a week).

We also have archived records showing the time information at a point in time, these are taken once a week, essentially they are snap shots.
It is possible for users to later put in a request to adjust the time on project. If this happens, the live record will reflect the correct time for the project, however the snapshots will not.
I need to write a query that goes through and updates these snapshots with the correct time for the project, at that point in time.

We have a table of SAP data, that has records for each time entry for a project, showing the project code it was for, the date it was for, and the amount of time. The Historical data table contains the code for the project and the date the snap shot was taken.
So I need to write a SQL query that will go through the historical data table, and for each row update the time spent by looking at the SAP table and getting all time entrys, for that project code, before the date that snapshot was taken.

I'm having real difficulty doing this in one SQL query, the main problem being I really need to run a query for each record in the historical data table. I keep coming up with pages suggesting using cursors, but I don't know much about them and keep seeing articles saying they are bad. Any suggestions on what sort of query I can use to get on the way with this would be great!

Essentially what I want to do in pseudocode is:

```
For Each Project Code in the hostorical data table, archived on a date, select all time entrys on or before that date.
```

**Sample tables**

```
Historical Project Data                          SAP Data
-----------------------                        ----------------
Project Code | run date                        Project Code | Time | Date
1234         | 01/09/2009                      1234         | 2    | 29/08/2009
9876         | 01/09/2009                      1234         | 5    | 29/08/2009
1234         | 07/09/2009                      9876         | 10   | 02/09/2009
9876         | 07/09/2009                      1234         | 2    | 03/09/2009
```

So I would like to end up with a query that shows

```
Project Code | run date   | time
1234         | 01/09/2009 | 7                      
9876         | 01/09/2009 | 0                      
1234         | 07/09/2009 | 9                      
9876         | 07/09/2009 | 10
```

So for example, the first record in the query shows all hours booked to project 1234, on or before the 01/09/2009

Comment: Ignore people saying cursors are bad. They just don't get it. If they try to hammer a nail into a wall using a drill, it's not the fault of the drill.

Comment: While I wouldn't say 'never use a cursor unless absolutely necessary' it is quite important to get in the habit of set-based logic and thinking. It's a mistake of many to always go straight to loops, cursors and procedural thinking when a very simple set-based query can solve the problem in an easy, simple and fast manner.

Comment: This has exactly what to do with Access?

Comment: @David W. Fenton: for 'cursor' read 'recordset'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to work based on the data you have provided:

```
create table #historical_project
(project_code int
,run_date datetime
)

create table #sap
(project_code int
,time_val int
,date datetime
)

insert #historical_project
      select 1234,'20090901'
union select 9876,'20090901'
union select 1234,'20090907'
union select 9876,'20090907'

insert #sap
      select  1234,2 , '20090829'
union select  1234,5 , '20090829'
union select  9876,10, '20090902'
union select  1234,2 , '20090903'


SELECT  *
        ,(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(time_val),0)
           FROM #sap                AS sp
           WHERE hp.project_code  = sp.project_code
           AND   hp.run_date     >= sp.DATE
          ) AS time
FROM #historical_project AS hp
ORDER BY run_date
         ,project_code
```

Answer (score 0):

As comments have suggested, it would be much simpler and more efficient to do it in a set-based way.  The main things to get your head around here are:

a) You can join on more than one condition

b) To get the row with 0 in the time column, you will need to use a left join (as there is no record in the right table) and convert the null to 0 with ISNULL()

The query below works on SQL Server:

```
--Set up for the example, you don't need this as you can access the permanend tables
DECLARE @HistoricalProjectData TABLE
    (
        ProjectCode int,
        Date        datetime
    )
INSERT INTO @HistoricalProjectData
VALUES
    (1234, '2009/09/01'),
    (9876, '2009/09/01'),
    (1234, '2009/09/07'),
    (9876, '2009/09/07')


DECLARE @SapData TABLE
    (
        ProjectCode int,
        Time        int,
        Date        datetime
    )
INSERT INTO @SapData
VALUES
    (1234, 2 , '2009/08/28'),
    (1234, 5 , '2009/08/29'),
    (9876, 10, '2009/09/02'),
    (1234, 2 , '2009/09/03')



--Replace the Table Variable names in here with the names of your tables.
SELECT
    his.ProjectCode,
    his.Date,
    SUM(ISNULL(sap.Time, 0))    AS  'TotalTime'

FROM
                @HistoricalProjectData  AS  his
    LEFT JOIN   @SapData                AS  sap ON  
                                                    sap.ProjectCode =   his.ProjectCode 
                                                AND 
                                                    sap.Date    <=  his.Date<=  his.Date

GROUP BY
    his.ProjectCode,
    his.Date

ORDER BY
    his.Date
```

Answer (score -2):

That's just a SELECT statement (with a non-equi join). I recommend learning basic SQL concepts before trying to do database development.

Comment: Well thats not exactly true, because the join needs to be on the project code and I need to get this data for each project code in the historical data table, which complicates it

Comment: Nothing prevents you from using a join condition like ... FROM a JOIN b ON b.date < a.date